# Problems with VPN (Hamachi, EasyVPN)

Tags: windows-7, vpn, hamachi

Im having a lot of problems with getting hamachi (and other similar VPN software) to work on my laptop. (Win7 Home Premium 32bit)
People can seem to ping me without problems, but trying to ping other people gives me "request timed out".

Ive tried everything (disabling firewall, antivirus) but nothing seems to help.

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Are both locations using the same IP range and subnet? Like 192.168.1.X and 255.255.255.X for example. If so, change the IP range or subnet being used on one end.

Comment: yes. both are using the same subnet.

Comment: Then it won't work.  You have to change one end.